# Connecting From Synapse Notebooks to an SQL Server Managed Instance Database Using Managed Identities

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I would like to read data directly from an SQL Server Managed Instance into a data frame in a notebook using Synapse's managed identity for authentication.

Permissions have been granted to the managed identity within the relevant database in the managed instance and a working linked service is in place within Synapse.

The below approach will work for an Azure SQL DB but when used against a Managed Instance generates an error of '`Message=Linked Service Type 'AzureSqlMI' not supported`'

```
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.yyy.database.windows.net:1234"
database = "AdventureWorks"
table = "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"
 
linked_service_name = "AdventureWorks"
 
access_token = mssparkutils.credentials.getConnectionStringOrCreds(linked_service_name)
 
df = spark.read \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("databaseName", database) \
    .option("accessToken", access_token) \
    .option("dbtable", table) \
    .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \
    .load()
 
display(df)
```

I also receive failures specifying the managed service id via `.option("msi_client_id", msi_id)` rather than indirectly obtaining a token.

Is there a workable method to connect with the managed identity. Our fall back approach will be to create an additional SQL user and store the name and password in a key vault but this will increase complexity of the solution and to some extent reduce the security of it.

The spark pool being used is running v3.3 of spark and the beta version of the spark mssql connector (spark-mssql-connector_2.12-1.3.0-BETA.jar) has been added manually as a workspace package.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```py
import requests
import json

resource_url = "https://database.windows.net/"
identity_endpoint = "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token"
headers = {"Metadata": "true"}
params = {"resource": resource_url, "api-version": "2018-02-01"}
response = requests.get(identity_endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)
access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising but on the first try 169.254.169.254 isn't responding to requests. I'll have to investigate more to figure out if the problem is universal or specific to the current set of firewalls, VPNs and so on that I'm working through right now.

Comment: So far I haven't managed to get the above to work. It's possible there's an issue specific to the tenant I'm working in but I can't find any evidence of synapse being able to send requests to 169.254.169.254 other than via mssparkutils.