# Connecting from Azure Synapse Analytics Spark Pool to Azure MI

Tags: pyodbc, azure-synapse, azure-sql-managed-instance, spark-jdbc

I need to connect (Read/Write) to Azure MI through the synapse notebook. Part of the data lives in ADLS Gen2, that I need to migrate to MI. I want to schedule this notebook to execute daily.

currently looking to use pyodbc and Jdbc libraries. I have used the below commands with same error message. I could not even find any relevant Microsoft Documentation on this.

token=TokenLibrary.getConnectionString(MILinkedServiceName)
token= mssparkutils.credentials.getConnectionStringOrCreds(MILinkedServiceName)

Error:

[image]

Checked the [Supported Linked Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-secure-credentials-with-tokenlibrary?pivots=programming-language-python#linked-service-connections-supported-from-the-spark-runtime), but there is nothing about Azure MI there.

I can not use Syanpse pipeline Copy/Data Flow for this requiment, becuase I need to write queries (Joins/Sunqueries) on Delta tables to fetch the relevant data for migration to MI. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"errorMessage":"[Code=LinkedServiceTypeNotSupported, Target=AzureSqlMI1, Message=Linked Service Type 'AzureSqlMI' not supported].
```

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-secure-credentials-with-tokenlibrary?pivots=programming-language-python#linked-service-connections-supported-from-the-spark-runtime) Azure SQL database Managed instance is not in the list of supported linked services.

[image]

That may be the reason to get the above error.
You can [Configure public endpoint - Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/public-endpoint-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal) and  use below code in spark notebook:

```
jdbcHostname = "<MIName>.public.da292b1d138f.database.windows.net"
jdbcDatabase = "<databasename>"
jdbcPort = "3342"
username = "<iuserName>"
password = "<password>"
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
"user" : username,
"password" : password,
"driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

}
query = "Select * from <tablename>"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

It will connect and read the data from SQL MI database successfully from spark notebook.

Comment: Thank you Bhavani. Two questions, 1) I don't want to add username/password directly  can we use something like TokenLibrary? 2) If I need to write MERGE/DELETE queries, it doesn't allow me to do that, hence was using pyodbc. Any thoughts?

Comment: can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77286066/connecting-from-synapse-notebooks-to-an-sql-server-managed-instance-database-usi) once?

Comment: Thank you Bhavani. We reached out to MS. They mentioned it is not possible to do this at this moment. Hence the error.